# Show/hide SelectItem in SmartGWT

Tags: smartgwt

Hi all first of all I´m noob using SmartGWT, I have a SelectItem component with setVisible(false) and added into a DynamicForm. This DynamicForm is added into a Layout. I need to set the SelectItem with visible to true when another component is changed.

I do this:

```
SelectItem -> setVisible(true);
DynamicForm -> .redraw();
Layout -> .redraw();
```

Comment: The selectItem componet keep hide

Comment: Try `selectItem.hide()`.

Comment: does not work, it is strange becose the setDisabled work fine

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks RAS, already work fine, I had two layout and I was doing redraw on one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following piece of code works, and toggles the visibility of SelectItem on button click.

However note that this could lead to a jumpy UI, as other form controls flow in and out to fill the gap.

A better approach would be to enable/disable the component as indicated in the comment, which does not require a redraw.

```
final DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
form.setWidth100();
form.setHeight100();

final SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem("sel", "Select");
selectItem.setValueMap("First", "Second", "Third");

ButtonItem buttonItem = new ButtonItem("btn", "Set");
buttonItem.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        selectItem.setVisible(!selectItem.getVisible());
        form.redraw();

        // uncomment following two lines and comment above two lines to enable/disable

        // boolean isDisabled = Boolean.TRUE.equals(selectItem.getDisabled());
        // selectItem.setDisabled(!isDisabled);
    }
});

form.setFields(selectItem, buttonItem);
```

Other ways to handle form layouts:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_form_sections
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_form_splitting